# How can I set all subdirectories of a directory into $PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, vscode-remote

Running vscode from my machine to remote server,I am trying to import some modules from parent directories. What is the correct way to import the modules from run.py? Do I have to setup a configuration json file in the *.vscode* folder? Since I have a lot of modules the solution with the os package is not very helpful. Is there a way of importing *all* the custom modules from the current working directory?

Thank you

```
  .
├── folder1
│   └── module1.py
├── folder2
│   └── module2.py
└── folder3
    └── run.py
```

VSCode 1.72.0
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You may use the command line as follows:

```bash
python3 -m folder3.run
```

The official docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).
Or another very detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3).